Flask Docker container not acecssible via Browser on Ubuntu
I created a simple flask API that I am deploying via docker. When I try to run it locally on my Ubuntu machine, the container runs but I cannot access any endpoint associated with the container.
api.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, send_file, make_response
import requests
import json
import psycopg2 as pg
import sqlalchemy as sql
from flask_cors import CORS
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import math
import os
import re

#own files
import support as sup
import sql as ssql

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/products", methods=["GET"])
def get_products()

    return {"Hello":"World"}


The api files itself contain no further instructions like "app.run()" or anything like that. Running Flask locally works. Deploying to our k8s cluster works too. It is just on the local ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 22.04) that I cannot access the container. For 127.0.0.1:5000/products, 0.0.0.0:5000/products and localhost:5000/products it throws a "This site can’t be reached" error
DOCKERFILE
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y libpq-dev

RUN pip install psycopg2-binary
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-science -y


EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "--app", "api", "run", "--host","0.0.0.0", "--debug"]

docker commands
sudo docker build -t api-test .
sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 api-test

docker output
* Serving Flask app 'api'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 114-686-213

I have looked through a lot of of posts detailing this very same issue. Most solutions are connected to the "--host","0.0.0.0" line or portmapping, both of which is given here.
Anyother ideas what could be happening?

UPDATE I tried using podman instead and it works! Since podman runs rootless, I can assume there is some sort of permissions issue with Docker on Ubuntu. Since the OG post I had purged docker-ce entirely, tried various port combinations, and ensured there was no firewall rule or other blocking the port.
